# Invalid Identifier ORA-00904 Error on Outer Join

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join, oracle19c, ora-00904

I'm attempting a query in Oracle SQL 19c that uses an outer join:

```
create table R(
a int,
b int
);

create table S(
b int,
c int,
d int
);

insert into R values (1,2);
insert into R values (3,4);
insert into R values (5,6);
insert into S values (2,4,6);
insert into S values (4,6,8);
insert into S values (4,7,9);

SELECT R.a, R.b, S.b, S.c, S.d
FROM R OUTER JOIN S
ON (R.a > S.b AND R.b = S.c)
```

The query throws `ORA-00904: "R"."B": invalid identifier` and from what I gather, the error is thrown on the second R.B (i.e., in the ON clause). I understand this has something to do with scoping rules but I do not understand what is going on in the above query as there is no nesting.

Comment: By the way, there are no brackets around the `on` clause. You can put them there, as in other random places, but they are ignored.

Comment: [`{ FULL | LEFT | RIGHT } [ OUTER ]`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem - unintuitively - is that you are missing a `LEFT` (or `RIGHT`, or `FULL`) keyword before the `OUTER JOIN`. You need to say what type of outer join it is:

```
SELECT R.a, R.b, S.b, S.c, S.d
FROM R LEFT OUTER JOIN S
ON (R.a > S.b AND R.b = S.c);
```

You seem to be getting that error because without one of those keywords, the parser is interpreting the `OUTER` as an alias for the `R` table - which means that `R.b` would not be correct, but `OUTER.b` would be. But, that would then be an inner join...

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2Z4Bp_iK)

Comment: Wow. I've never come across that but it makes perfect sense.

Comment: I had (erroneously) assumed that an outer join was FULL by default. I wouldn't have thought that Oracle would allow a keyword to be used as an alias.

Comment: @soporific312 - I don't think it would allow a *reserved* word, depending on which order the parser checks things; but `outer` isn't quite in that category, it's 'just' a keyword. I would imagine for historic reasons as the ANSI syntax was added in Oracle 9i, and make it reserved then could have broken old code. The joys of having to maintain backward compatibility...